# Extending Content Moderator PII Detection

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to train the Cognitive Services Content Moderator using the terms API or another API?

It looks like terms are just used to create basic screens (string matches) based on the sample provided.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Content-Moderator/term-lists-quickstart-dotnet.md

Comment: Did you get this to work ?

Comment: There wasn't a way to extend it.  We used regular expressions instead of CM.